# How to parse a property value only in the nested schema?

Tags: python, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I use **marshmallow** to dump my **SQLAlchemy** entity to JSON as it shown below:

```
class EntitySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
    children = fields.List(Nested(ChildSchema(only=("id",))))
```

The problem is the code above produces JSON with nested objects instead of pure int-list:

```
{
    ...
    "children": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
}
```

How to tell **marshmallow** to parse only value of `id` property: `"children": [1, 2]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Pluck` field:

```
class EntitySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
    children = fields.List(fields.Pluck(ChildSchema, "id"))
```